# Why do I get a syntax error when using a spread operator?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm using ES6's spread operator with Babel as a transpiler to ES5. When I use the spread operator like so:

```
const { height, weight, radius, ...otherValues } = sphere;
```

I get a `SyntaxError`:

```
ERROR in ./src/sphere.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (7:36)

   6 | 
>  7 |   const { height, weight, radius, ...otherValues } = sphere;
     |                                   ^
   8 |
```

Why is this?

Comment: I already know the answer to my question but had a hard time finding the answer on StackOverflow, so [I'm posting the question and answer I would have found helpful](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Comment: FYI, [`...` is not an operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151966/what-is-spreadelement-in-ecmascript-documentation-is-it-the-same-as-spread-oper/37152508#37152508). In your example it's a "rest property".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Babel doesn't transpile the spread operator out of the box. You also need to install the [babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread) plugin for Babel. Once you've installed that package, your code should compile with no further changes.

Comment: You need to install stage preset as well. "npm install --save-dev babel-preset-stage-0", If there is babelrc file, add the stage-0 preset.